# Routing in ASP.NET Web Site

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-routing

I would like to know if [Routing features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) works on ASP.NET web sites. I know it works on Web Applications, registering my routes inside the **Application_Start** method.

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   RegisterRoutes(...)
 }
```

I'm using **Visual Web Developer 2008 Exp. Ed.**, **.NET Framework 3.5** and I created a new **Web Site**: ***File*** > **New Web Site...**

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: very simple article http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/10/13/url-routing-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx

Comment: @AbiRuban Thanks, but I'm using .NET Framework 3.5 and I don't have access to some **RouteCollection** members like **MapRoute**.

Comment: If you're using .NET Framework 3.5, you need to implement UrlRoutingModule

Comment: @AbiRuban Hey! That worked. After I searched for UrlRoutingModule implementation I found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668202(v=vs.90).aspx) and my problem got solved!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Global.asax within an ASP.NET web site using visual studio that gives you access to the Application_Start event.  Just Add New Item and select Global Application Class